# How to find if pair exists in a given table in Kusto?

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

fairly new to KQL. I need to find if a certain pair of associated values (x,y) exists in a table (T).

My thought was to write the line:

```
let T =
...
...
...
DataTable
| where x, y in T
```

but the in operator only takes one argument as input, so this does not work. How can I find only x,y pairs that exist in T?

Comment: In which column(s) are you searching for x and y? Does your table T have an 'x' and a 'y' column? If so, that would be T | where x == 'x' and y == 'y'.

Comment: @yifats x and y are columns in DataTable and T. T has been filtered down to contain a subset of x and y. I want to only use those filtered x,y pairs for additional operations in DataTable. That is why I want to essentially check if each x,y pair in DataTable exists in T. There is no static string I can check the column against because I don't care about what the value is, just that it exists in T. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think you're looking for a join between the tables. Will the following work for you? 
Return all records from DataTable for which x,y exist in T. Note that it's recommended to place the smaller data set on the left side of the join, so you may want to switch the order based on your datasets.

```
let T = datatable(x:string, y:string)
[
    "A", "B" 
];
let DataTable = datatable(x:string, y:string, col1:long)
[
    "A", "B", 1,
    "C", "D", 2
];
T
| join kind=inner DataTable on x,y
| project-away x1, y1
```

[image]